# Visual Studio output display in new tab instead of console or windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins

I am developing a data analysis tool for an inhouse project that displays the projected output using custom made heat-bars and zedgraph charts in a windows form. I am using C# and made a visual studio plugin (plugin is a requirement) that loads the form and as invoked and shows everything properly. But I was wondering if I could load/display the result in a new tab in Visual Studio IDE, not in a console or in a windows form.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you simply asking if this is possible? Because the answer to that question is yes, it is entirely possible to create your own window/tab in Visual Studio with an addon.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my incomplete question. I am new to VS addin development and some help in "how to do that" is highly appreciated.

Comment: SO needs a "do-my-work-for-me" tag